# Generalizing recursion/loops in Swift

Tags: ios, algorithm, swift

I'm struggling with generalizing this example code in Swift:

```
let words = [ ant, apple, banana, bear, cucumber, cheese ]

... // some sorting code

var sentences = [String]()

for aWord in wordsThatStartWithA {
    bWord in wordsThatStartWithB {
        cWord in wordsThatStartWithC {
            sentences.append("\(aWord) \(bWord) \(cWord)")
        }
    }
}

// sentences -> "ant banana cucumber", "apple banana cucumber", "ant bear cucumber", ...
```

The aim is to get all combinations that contain one a-word, one b-word and one c-word, in that order. But I want to be able to generalize this to any sequence (ie. acb, acdqp, etc.)

Ideally I want to pass a string like "acd" into a function that returns an array of sentences that match. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution. Inside a `Template` struct:

```
func sentencesWithWords(words: [String]) -> [String] {

    // Group vocabulary into set of template options
    let optionsSets = template.map { descriptor in
        return words.filter({ $0.matchesDescriptor(descriptor) })
    }

    // Iterate through options set
    var sentences = [String]()
    for options in optionsSets {

        // Append each option to each existing sentence
        var newSentences = [String]()
        for option in options {
            if sentences.count == 0 {
                newSentences.append(option)
            } else {
                for sentence in sentences {
                    newSentences.append("\(sentence) \(option)")
                }
            }
        }

        sentences = newSentences
    }

    return sentences
}
```